# How to print the number of digits of a number that is entered by the user in C?

Tags: c, scanf, eof

Hello I am trying to write C code that prompts the user for a positive integer and then prints out the number of digits in that number. Assuming that the user enters a positive integer, no error checking is needed.

My problem is after 'ctrl-d' is pressed the output is always:

"# of digits = 1"

If the user types 1023 the program should print:

"# of digits = 4"

I am new to C and am trying to get a feel for how scanf works. Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int count = 0;
char n;
printf("Enter positive int!\n");

   while(scanf("%c",&n) != EOF);
    {
     count++;
    }

printf("# of digits = %d\n", count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after the `while`. Hint: put braces on the same line as the `while`/`if` etc.

Comment: `%c` in `scanf` will count the newline that the user enters after the number.

Comment: Please don't silently edit the real error out of your code. This changes the contents of it completely.

Comment: `scanf` blocks until you end with enter or Ctrl+D

Comment: Understood, thank you and sorry about that silent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `%d` format specifier enter an decimal integer with [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), then apply following function:

```
int getNumOfDigits(int num, int base /*= 10*/)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (num < 0) {
        num = -num;
    }
    while (num > 0) {
        count++;
        num /= base;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It is untested, but general idea is to divide by ten, then you go with number of digits of an `int` number:

```
printf("# of digits = %d\n", getNumOfDigits(number, 10));
```

Note that you should also check returned value from `scanf` for error handling (when number is not in correct format). For instance:

```
if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) {
    printf("Incorrent input for decimal number!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: What if the user types `00100`; your code will count three digits, the fixed version of the code in the question would say five digits.  Either, or both, could be the right answer to a specific question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It depends, what `00100` means to user. It may be an octal number, then one should use `%i` f.s. to allow other bases (oct, hex). But, it would be likely truncated to `100` and that is desired output as I think, because such leading zeros are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read in a string and then use `strlen()` to check its length:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 64

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buf[MAX_LEN] = {0};

    scanf("%s", buf);    
    fprintf(stdout, "string length: %lu\n", strlen(buf));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you need to validate the input (i.e., to ensure it is a number), you could read in the string as above, and before printing the string length, loop over each character and use `isdigit()` to test if that character is an integer. If it isn't, then the input is either a negative number or some other non-numerical character.

Comment: `scanf` with `%s` == `gets` (and `gets` was so terrible that ISO deprecated it).

Comment: I'm not sure they are equivalent, but you could probably use `scanf("%63s", buf)` to avoid an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to find the number of digits by using `log10()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned number;
    scanf("%u", &number);
    printf("%.0f\n", ceil(log10((double)number+1)));
    return 0;
}
```

And here is another way, `sprintf()` returns the number of characters written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned number;
    char str[20];
    scanf("%u", &number);
    printf("%d\n", sprintf(str,"%u", number));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ooh oh mybad. Now added 1, thank you.